# Unicode String Issue

Tags: unicode, gdb

I am storing some unicode characters "лфи" in a char array.
When I view(x/30s ) the values in gdb it show me something like:

0x80ac47c: "?\004>\004 "
0x80ac482: "A\0048\004;\004L\004D\004>\004=\004:\0045\004/"

Why it is happening so and what are these \004 representing?

Comment: Use `x/hs addr` command, and please refer this link: [http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1860/printing-unicode-strings-in-gdb-in-osx](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1860/printing-unicode-strings-in-gdb-in-osx).

Answer (score 1):

You should read [gdb's character set documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Character-Sets.html#Character-Sets), since it seems gdb is escaping these characters instead of letting the terminal display them.

Answer (score 1):

See [Gdb Unicode Printing](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~caolan/pub/guides/GdbUnicodePrinting.txt). If you overload the `dbg_dump` function in your code, by invoking `print dbg_dump("лфи")` inside gdb it will hopefully invoke your overloaded function, resulting in proper UTF-8 representation. Remember, in your custon `dbg_dump` you may need to explicitly express that you want to display Unicode characters.